# Set Notepad++ Linewrap indentation to 2 characters?

Tags: notepad++

In Notepad++ 6.6.9, I have set **Linewrap** to **Indent**:

[image]

However, this indents by **4** characters. How can I make this indent by **2** characters instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Settings>Preferences... go to "Tab Settings" in the left column. In that window, change the "Tab size" value.

[image: Tab size]